# How do I draw a linear layout over a relative layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

My code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".homepage"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <!--wavy background-->
    <RelativeLayout                                
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300sp"
        android:background="@drawable/wave">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="CGA Dashboard"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--wavy background-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            
             <!---some code here --->

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            <!---some code here --->

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Inside the parent `linear layout`, I have a child `relative layout` which contains a wavy background.

But when I execute the code the child `linear layout` renders below the `relative layout` as shown in the output below:

[Please click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L1Pe.png)

I want to move the child `linear layout` a little up so that it renders over the `relative layout`. How do I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to draw something over something, you should use not `LinearLayout`, but `FrameLayout`, because `LinearLayout` draws its children from top to bottom or from left to right.

**More than that, it's not recommended to use `RelativeLayout` because of its low performance. You should consider `ConstraintLayout` instead.**

But if you will stick with your current layout, just use FrameLayout as parent, something like that:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".homepage"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <!--wavy background-->
    <RelativeLayout                                
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300sp"
        android:background="@drawable/wave">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="CGA Dashboard"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--wavy background-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            
             <!---some code here --->

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            <!---some code here --->

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```